K&R C, 1.13 - PECULIAR error in the frequency count
#define IN  1
#define OUT 0
void horizontal_histogram(){
    int wl[21]; // taking max word length to be 20.
    
    int c, state, cc = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < 21; i++){
        wl[i] = 0;
    }
    state = OUT;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n'){
            if(state == IN){
                wl[cc] += 1;
                cc = 0;
            }
            state = OUT;
        }else{
            if(state == OUT){
                state = IN;

            }
                cc++;
            
        }
    }
    printf("\n3 \'|||\' equals 1 count. [LENGTH]: [COUNT]\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++){
        printf("\n%4d:",i+1);
        for(int k=0; k < wl[i]; k++){
            printf("|||");
        }
    }
}

Initially I was successful in getting the expected result for the horizontal histogram, after I tried running the vertical version, a peculiar error has started appearing. No matter what change I do wl[0] seems to be always == 25.
A sample o/p for even horizontal histogram.
HI ALL 123 1234

3 '|||' equals 1 count. [LENGTH]: [COUNT]

   1:|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
   2:|||
   3:||||||
   4:|||
   5:
   6:
   7:
   8:
   9:
  10:
  11:
  12:
  13:
  14:
  15:
  16:
  17:
  18:
  19:
  20:
  21:

There are 75(25*3) '|' lines for word frequency of length 1.
The code-block in vertical-histogram which probably messed things up.
for(int k=25; k >=0; k--){
        for(int l=0; l < 21; l++){
            if(k<=wl[l]){
                
                // some logic
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

I am running these programs on a VM. At this point I just want to know why exactly is this happening any flaws in my logic or some buffer overflow stuff etc.=. Thanks in advance.

We can probably guess what IN and OUT are, but especially if you are getting weird behavior, it is important to provide a complete [mre].

Does the book not tell you to initialize wl?

You did not initialize wl. You also have an off-by-one error and a premature termination condition.

@Dúthomhas can you please point out where do I have those latter 2 errors?

Is the error in the book? or the code is yours.  Can you answer to this?  IMHO the errata of K&R doesn't receive much traffic lately.

The error was on my end, I had updated the above code as per the suggestions of the above comments, I missed initializing the elements of wl to 0.
